# Unable to hide the ribbon button using custom action

Tags: 2013, custom-actions, pages

I have created one content type inheriting from Pages content type, and applied it to Pages library in publishing web.

I want to hide the Publish button from the ribbon. To do so, I have created one custom action which contains following code.

```
<CustomAction
Id="RemovePublishButton"
Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
RegistrationId="0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900D9A1C3A07CE50544B51A08234D0D26DE"
RegistrationType="ContentType">
<CommandUIExtension>
  <CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition
      Location="Ribbon.PublishTab.Publishing.Publish" />
  </CommandUIDefinitions>
</CommandUIExtension>
</CustomAction>
```

I have referred [this](http://sharepointegg.blogspot.in/2010/02/remove-button-from-ribbon-in-sharepoint.html) link for hiding button from ribbon. But unfortunately, it is not getting invisible. I have corrected the location form [this MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee537543%28v=office.15%29.aspx) link also.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

After googling I found one solution that if we omit `RegistrationId` and `RegistrationType` attributes from `<CustomAction>`, we can hide the button. The actual reason behind this is not yet clear to me but working like charm!!! Now my custom action is containing following code.

```
<CustomAction
Id="RemovePublishButton"
Location="CommandUI.Ribbon">
<CommandUIExtension>
  <CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition
      Location="Ribbon.PublishTab.Publishing.Publish" />
  </CommandUIDefinitions>
</CommandUIExtension>
</CustomAction>
```

Hope this helps others too!!!